# Search Term Redirect URL. Relative Path instead of Full URL Path?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, search

When editing a Search Query, why doesn't Magento allow the Redirect URL to be Relative Paths like `/section/subsection` or `/best-product`. It enforces the full URL which is kind of pain. How would you change this and is there any reasons to consider not changing this?

Magento Documents its [Search Term Redirect Functionality](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-redirect-search-terms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test by removing the JS validation `validate-url` seemed to work without any issues for me, so with that in mind:

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Search/Edit/Form.php:

In function `_prepareForm()`

Change this:

```
$fieldset->addField('redirect', 'text', array(
    'name'  => 'redirect',
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Redirect URL'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Redirect URL'),
    'class' => 'validate-url',
    'note'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ex. http://domain.com'),
));
```

To this:

```
$fieldset->addField('redirect', 'text', array(
    'name'  => 'redirect',
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Redirect URL'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Redirect URL'),
    //'class' => 'validate-url',
    //'note'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ex. http://domain.com'),
));
```

NOTE: obviously do not just edit core but extend the Adminhtml Block.

Comment: One question. You said you tested this. Did having a relative path seem to effect the redirection functionality?

Comment: It was a simple spot check, but appeared to work without issue. I'm not sure the specifics why they chose absolutes vs relative, so testing the above would be best.

Comment: This officially works in production. I made a module. If anyone is interested, let me know.

Comment: put it up on github please.